# Which attribute to choose first (the root) when making a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning

I am a bit confused, as it seems like my teacher has told me something different than what I see and hear on *YouTube* videos.

**My problem is as follows:**

My teacher told us to that the *probability* when deciding the root of the decision tree needs to be as close to 50% as possible. So, let's say we have this table:

[image]

My teacher told me for the `ID3 algorithm`, we can *"clearly see, without having to calculate the `information gain`, that we need to pick "Growling" as our root as this is 50%, hence the 4 times YES and 4 times NO"*

Well, okay, but why? When I check YouTube videos, they say that we need to take the most pure ones, so the ones where we have the most difference (like: 7 times YES and 0 times NO), which is certainly not "growling", as it's `impure`...

As you can see I am confused. Is this 50% strictly for the ID3 algorithm or is there something I am missing here? Could someone help me out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID3 algorithm would first takes growling because creates two nodes that are overall purer than the root:
root has 3 yes and 5 no, if you use growling to split your data you'll have 2 yes and 2 no in one node (that can be splitted using smelly) and 1 no and 3 yes in the other node. the first node gives you an information loss, the second one an information gain, the algorithm calculates the mean of the two measures, and finding it positive, performs the split. information gain (loss is his negative) is based on entropy, which measures the heterogeneity of the response variable in the nodes.

Comment: But does this mean that you first need to check what comes AFTER you would hypothetically choose some root? I mean, do you choose the root here because it's 2 YES and 2 NO or because of the possibilities after you would choose this?

Comment: you choose the variable for performing the split for the information gain that you will get choosing it, and that's calculeted on nodes created by the split, so, yes.

Comment: Okay, but does this mean that the information gain of an element with 2 yes and 2 no is higher than 3 yes 5 no?

Comment: no, entropy of a node wtih 2 yes and 2 no is higher than one with 3 yes and 5 no, so there's an information loss. however, this is averaged with the information gain from the other node, which has a lower entropy, and the overall information gain is positive

Comment: You say no, but you also state that a node with 2 yes and 2 no is higher... higher what? Higher information gain? If so, why do you say no? Can you be more concise / precise please?

Comment: higher entropy. I see you don't understand how does it all work, so I suggest you to read some more complete explanations, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain, or http://www.math.unipd.it/~aiolli/corsi/0708/IR/Lez12.pdf (first pages only)